# Angular CDK Overlay to one component

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-cdk

I am trying to use the CDK Overlay to add a material spinner as a loading indicator over the top of a specific component. However, when I set hasBackdrop to true the entire application is grayed and disabled. I am trying to pass in the viewContainerRef from the component and am using connectedTo positioning. I can move the spinner location around, but not alter the area being disabled by the backdrop.

```js
@Injectable()
export class WaitIndicatorService {

    overlayRef: OverlayRef;
    constructor(public overlay: Overlay) { }

    showSpinner(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
        const config = new OverlayConfig();

        config.positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
/*             .global()
            .centerHorizontally()
            .centerVertically(); */

             .connectedTo(viewContainerRef.element,
            { originX: 'start', originY: 'bottom'},
            { overlayX: 'start', overlayY: 'bottom' });

        config.hasBackdrop = true;

        this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);
        this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(WaitSpinnerPanelComponent, viewContainerRef));
    }

    hideSpinner(): void {
        this.overlayRef.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this working for you now?

Comment: I ended up just living with the disable of the whole app as I could not get it working for a particular component and had to move on to other things.

Answer (score 1):

What you miss in your code is the reference to the specific DOM element you're trying to attach the spinner to. You can pass that reference with the `cdkOverlayOrigin` directive and then attach the overlay to the `overlayorigin.elementRef` with `config.hasBackdrop` option set to `false`.

In the host component:

```
<div cdkOverlayOrigin #overlayorigin="cdkOverlayOrigin"></div>

@ViewChild(OverlayOrigin) overlayrigin: OverlayOrigin;
```

In your spinner component:

```
showSpinner(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, overlayorigin: OverlayOrigin): void {
...
config.positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
             .connectedTo(overlayorigin.elementRef,
......
```

Comment: Hi, i want to display the backdrop to a particular component. Can u please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: I'd like to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you have a link to your project or a test set-up, or can you just paste code here?

Comment: @RedDree I am using content Projection and calling an generic component. How can i add cdk overlay to the same

Comment: @SunilBehera I can take a look at your code with pleasure if you post a link to a Stackblitz project or any other Angular playground. It sounds interesting.

Comment: From what you're saying, it is quite doable because your generic component is still an Angular component and it renders some HTML. What you need to think of is 1. The timing (what is rendered first? what are the events that you have control over before, during, after your generic component renders its children), 2. What HTML element can serve as the overlay origin i.e. what element you can attach the overlay to.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog entry: https://itnext.io/a-loader-for-your-components-with-angular-cdk-overlay-ebf5a4962e4d

You have to extend OverlayContainer with a new service and make the field _containerElement  accessible:

```
public setContainerElement(containerElement: HTMLElement): void {
  this._containerElement = containerElement;
}
```

Then you have to extent Overlay with a new service and use your extended OverlayContainer in the constructor. Add a custom create function:

```
public createWithContainer(containerElement: HTMLElement, options): OverlayRef {
    this._myOverlayContainer.setContainerElement(containerElement);
    return super.create(options);
}
```